# Can't Insert Time into MySQL Database (C# or SQL Doesnt work)

Tags: mysql, database

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I cannot insert ANYTHING into this table in C# or MySQL (using MySQL Workbench)

Edit > Removed C#

MySQL Returns: "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'session_start' in 'field list'"

Will dump code

So I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `verbose_session_log` (
  `log_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `session_length` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_start` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`),
  KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `verbose_session_log_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_name`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

The user_name references this table:
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `confirmed_code` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_time_login` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `max_words_per_day` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
  `max_words_limit` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
  `sign_up_date` date NOT NULL,
  `account_type` varchar(16) DEFAULT 'user',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This is the last thing I tried in MySQL

```
INSERT INTO `verbose_session_log`
(`log_id`,
`user_name`,
`session_length`,
`session_start`,
`session_end`,
`date`)
VALUES
(
1,
'dailytest',
current_time(),
current_time(),
current_time(),
current_date());
```

Note: Normally Date, ID and Session_Length are handled by triggers, but it gives me the same error regardless.
I tried the current values:

```
TIME(NOW());
ADDTIME(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOURS);
```

I've pretty much tried everything.

Edit 2 > I attempted an insert using the PHPMyAdmin tool and that also gives me an unknown column session_start in fieldlist.

Maybe there is an issue with the table declarations?

I added the users table SHOW CREATE TABLE output.

EDIT 3 > Triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `verbose_session_log_date_session_length_trigger`
BEFORE INSERT ON `verbose_session_log`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.`date` = NOW();
   SET NEW.`session_length` = TIMEDIFF(`session_start`, `session_end`);

END$$
DELIMITER $
```

Note I updated the user field (it was `DEFAULT NULL` but is now `NOT NULL, didnt change anything)

Comment: You are missing your closing `)`  in your sql string. Was that a copy error?

Comment: Yeah missed that one, `Now it just gives me Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'session_start' in 'field list'.` Thanks

Comment: Your C# code is (for a start) irrelevant since the error is returned by MySql directly. In your case, I don't know why: I just copied and pasted to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d787/1) (I just removed the foreign key definition) and it works just fine for me. Are you sure you copied everything?

Comment: Put a `@` in front of your parameter names in your `AddWithValue` statements

Comment: @Jcl I attempted both SQL Fiddle, DBForge for MySQL (eww), PHPMyAdmin & MySQL Workbench. I think there is an issue with the table declaration, but I cannot spot it.

Comment: @JRLambert Yeah, forgot this one time, thanks.

Comment: @Memhave the link in my comment ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d787/1) has a working table / insert, so unless there's something different which you haven't shown us, it's working for me

Comment: Sorry I didnt see the link, I looked at it, you are right it works. I think theres an issue somewhere else. I will try to recreate the schema in SQL Fiddle (just the two tables)

Comment: @Memhave I even made a second fiddle including the foreign key (and both tables), and it works and inserts just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/107aad . I've just copied and pasted your code. Removed the `InnoDB` part since it's not supported by SQL Fiddle but the rest is identical

Comment: I'm going to drop the table and recreate it, as the tables listed above are ones dumped by MySQL Workbench. I appreciate the help and I will report back.

Comment: @Jcl I'm still getting the message, I'm adding the triggers to the question. I *think* they are the issue but I am getting desperate.

Comment: Triggers could indeed be the cause. Add them and we'll have a look :-)

Comment: Now we are off to somewhere, let me add an answer

Comment: There is an event which pulls data from the table, is it needed? Its a pretty big eye-sore.

Comment: @Memhave I think the problem is in the trigger, please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger is:

```sql
BEFORE INSERT ON `verbose_session_log`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.`date` = NOW();
   SET NEW.`session_length` = TIMEDIFF(`session_start`, `session_end`);
END
```

Obviously, now the problem is that `session_start` (and `session_end`) in that trigger are not referring to any table. In case `session_start` and `session_end` refer to the values on each inserted row (should be), change that line to:

```sql
SET NEW.`session_length` = TIMEDIFF(NEW.`session_start`, NEW.`session_end`);
```

Comment: As a side note (not related to the question), that schema looks fishy, to say the least, what if `session_start` happens at 23:59 and `session_end` happens at `00:01`? You'd get a `session_length` of 23 hours and 58 minutes? Why not storing the whole `datetime` in `session_start` and `session_end`?

Comment: Damn. I cant believe I made that simple mistake. So much time lost. I feel pretty shit >:(. Thanks though!

Comment: That happens. Take some rest ;-)

Comment: I considered storing date times, but not for that reason. It does make sense though I will change the schema definition. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Memhave also, although the concept is wrong for a start (since you get problems when a session involves a change in the day), you probably rather mean `TIMEDIFF(session_end, session_start)`, since you want to substract the start time to the end time (that is: `end_time - start_time`), and not reverse